# Updating values using Python user input

Tags: python, pandas, function, numpy, input

I have a dataset where, whenever the date value in the 'Update' column is updated, the other
columns will be updated as well. Logic is:

```
Date1 is 3 months from Date2
Date2 is 1 month from Date3
and Update is 1 month from Date3
```

**The only data that is changing is the dates, which are essentially getting shifted based upon the user input.**

**Data**

```
Date1       Date2       Date3       Update
1/1/2021    4/1/2021    5/1/2021    6/1/2021
5           2           1           1
```

**Desired**

Input prompt will ask user which date value they wish to input.
User inputs the date '8/1/2021', which updates the remaining column date values.

```
Date1       Date2       Date3       Update
3/1/2021    6/1/2021    7/1/2021    8/1/2021
5           2           1           1
```

**Doing**

I believe I can use a combination of a function as well as user prompt to approach this problem.

```
#take input
datevalue = input("Enter date value: ")
print(datevalue)




#use input variable in function or script to create date update
s = df['Update'].str.replace(r'(\S+) (\S+)', r'\2\1')
df['Update'] = (pd.PeriodIndex(s, freq='D') + 3).strftime('D%q %Y')
```

I am looking for **some starting point suggestion or a good foundation/documentation** on how to best approach this problem. I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: So basically, update all dates with the difference between `Update` and the user input (`all dates = all dates + (user input - Update)`)?

Comment: @user17242583 update Date1 Date2 and Date3 based on the date value entered in the Update column.
Date1 and Date2 are 3 months apart.
Date2 and Date3 is 1 month apart.
Date3 and Update is 1 month apart.

Comment: Ah I see, so the user input gets put int the update column, and then the other columns get updated based on that...ok, should be easy.

Comment: Yes the values would get updated based on logic and what user inputs @user17242583

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data format is a bit messy, but this should work for you:

```
datevalue = pd.to_datetime(input("Enter date value: "))

df = df.T
df[1] = df[1].astype(int)
df.loc['Update', 1] = 0
df[0] = df[1].apply(lambda x: datevalue - pd.DateOffset(months=x))
df = df.T
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                 Date1                Date2                Date3               Update
0  2021-03-01 00:00:00  2021-06-01 00:00:00  2021-07-01 00:00:00  2021-08-01 00:00:00
1                    5                    2                    1                    0
```

Comment: is 'T' the variable that holds what the user inputs @user17242583? - or where would the user input '08-01-2021'? thanks

Comment: Oh sorry @Lynn! I forgot about that part. No `T` is for transpose, and it's an alias for [`transpose()`, a built-in method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) of DataFrames, and it basically rotates the dataframe 90°.

Comment: right I see now. Ok what tells the user which input to enter?

Comment: Check now @Lynn.

Comment: oh datevalue input with variable I see- is there documentation on the lambda? I will research documentation on lambda

Comment: oh and where in the code does it specify that Date1 is 5 months delta from Update column? @user17242583

Comment: this works, but could you please add notes to explain where the date diff specifications are? thank you? (where in the code does it specify: Date1 and Date2 are 3 months apart etc) thanks

Comment: Basically all I'm doing is temporarily working the dataframe into a specific format so that I can select all the numbers as one list, and then for each of those numbers, I subtract that number (as months) from the user-entered value. Does that make sense?

Comment: ok, so if I wanted to further customize it to where the Update column is, say 10months from Date1, where would I specify? would I use an index @us17242583er

Comment: As long as the `Update` column is named `Update`, and the second row of the dataframe contains the month offsets, my code should work. Hopefully I'm understanding you...

Comment: oh I'd like the values under the date columns to remain the same. The values under the date column have no relation to the delta in months @user17242583

Comment: ah ok no the second row values have no relation to month offsets user17242583

Comment: Oh, do you want the _second_ row to be updated based on the _months_ of the columns?

Comment: no the only values that should be changing are Date1, Date2, Date3 and Update values (where the user enters the date) @user17242583

Comment: Was just looking into code that reflect these rules: 
Date1 is 3 months from Date2.
Date2 is 1 month from Date3.
and Update is 1 month from Date3 - based on user input

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240119/discussion-between-user17242583-and-lynn).